FastAPI running in IIS - Getting permissionError:[WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions
I'm trying to setup FastAPI in IIS using hypercorn and I keep getting the error
PermissionError: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

I followed these steps https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/discussions/4207#discussioncomment-2216634
My web.config is the following
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers accessPolicy="Read, Execute, Script">
            <remove name="httpPlatformHandler"/>
            <add name="httpPlatformHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" />
        </handlers>
        <httpPlatform processPath="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\FastAPI\Scripts\python.exe"
            arguments="-m hypercorn app.main:app --bind 127.0.0.1:8080 --keep-alive 5 --worker-class asyncio --workers 4"
            stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile="C:\logs\python.log" startupTimeLimit="120" requestTimeout="00:05:00"
            startupRetryCount="3" processesPerApplication="1">
        </httpPlatform>
        <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>

If I stop IIS and I run the command below it works fine, it's only when running it inside IIS.
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\FastAPI\Scripts\python.exe -m hypercorn app.main:app --bind 127.0.0.1:8080 --keep-alive 5 --worker-class asyncio --workers 4


I also tried to grant IIS_IUSRS access to python.exe but it didn't make any difference, it was suggested in this post as when calling the API it hangs forever
I suspect it's something to do with the IIS port binding, if I change the web.config to point at another port (e.g. 8000) different than the binding port in IIS then I'm able to access the API (e.g. by navigating to http://localhost:8000), it feels to me IIS is using the port when hypercorn is trying to use it


Sounds like you are using a virtual environment, which can make things much more complicated. You will have to follow my post to use the global interpreter which causes less trouble on permissions.

@LexLi yes! I should have mentioned that, you mean this post  (https://docs.lextudio.com/blog/running-flask-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/#the-infinite-loading) or something else? I'd ideally like to run it in a virtual environment but I'll try without it

@LexLi I tried without virtaul environment and I still get the same issue so it must be something else

If you simply follow my blog post to get started with a brand new FastAPI project, does it work? Your current project has an invalid web.config file (for example —bind is clearly wrong and I don’t know from where you learned it).

You can use tools such as netstat or Resource Monitor to help you view the network connections and port usage that are running on your system. These tools can tell you which processes are using which ports, and can help you determine if there are other applications occupying the specific port you are trying to use in Hypercorn (such as port 8080). By viewing this information, you can confirm whether the port is occupied by another application and which processes are using it.

@LexLi you are absolutely right! I wasn't aware you wrote a post specifically on FastAPI, that worked for me and seems to be working with virtual environments too. I should have used uvicorn, the issue seems to be with hypercorn, when I switch it back I get the same error message as before but it works with uvicorn. Please write an answer and I'll mark it as the solution. Leaving the link to your post (https://docs.lextudio.com/blog/running-fastapi-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/)

I don’t need more points, so you can write up what you learned as an answer and accept it.

This turned out to be an issue with hypercorn (I raised an issue in their github repo https://github.com/pgjones/hypercorn/issues/231)
I switched to use uvicorn as @Lex Li suggested following his blog post and it's now working fine
